# Escaping "?" in a constructed MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search the database for a record with an attribute of `?`.

When I construct the query similar to the one below it expects a parameter to be passed in as well.

```
select id FROM / * table * / WHERE fullname = '?' AND ......
```

Is there any easy way around this? I've tried using a \? in the string instead, but with the same result.

Thanks for the suggestions, the problem is that the query was being passed to another part of the software to be pushed to the database and it was struggling to deal with the "?".

Comment: Is php or mysql complaining about the questionmark?

Comment: i do not get what the actual problem is?

Comment: This query works in MySQL, e.g. in MySQL console. Possible that was an  issue of your MySQL client. Why table name is commented?

Comment: Calling the attribute `?` was not a very smart move. If you're using MySQLi, you're toast. If you're using PDO, consider named parametrization.

Comment: The attribute has been named that way by the CMS we're using. It's a terrible design flaw, but the records marked with "?" usually never have to be queried.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast it's an error from PHP saying that it expects 1 parameter and 0 were given.

Comment: Can we see the php code then?

Comment: Alt those `LIKE '%'` answers seem wrong, as % is the many wild-card in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is prepared statement in PDO; you can try this:

   ```
   $statement = $connection->prepare( "select id FROM tablename WHERE fullname = ? AND ..";
   $statement->bindParam( 1, '?', PDO::PARAM_STR );
   ```
2. If it is a simple MySQL query, you don't need to escape the `?` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `like`..

```
    select id FROM / * table * / WHERE fullname like '%?%' AND ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LIKE %%`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) comparison function in clauses to match `?` in your desired column. In this way you will find matches which contains your input string instead of exact matches which you would find with equal comparison operator

```
select id FROM / * table * / WHERE fullname LIKE '%?%' AND ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select id FROM / * table * / WHERE fullname  LIKE '%?%%' ESCAPE '?';
```